# Как установить соединение Socket.IO между двумя серверами соединенных по LAN

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, apache, socket.io, mikrotik

**Есть два сервера, на каждом установлена: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS и панель VestaCP**

**Сервер №1**

Установлен сайт "**aaa.ru**", на нём подключен Socket.IO:

```
var socket = io("https://www.aaa.ru:8600/", {secure: false});
```

Сервер имеет внешний ip: 111.111.111.111 и 2 ethernet:

1. Подключен интернет с внешним ip
2. Подключен роутер Mikrotik

**Сервер №2**

Установлен сайт "**bbb.ru**" и Node.js + Socket.IO, который должен отвечать на запрос с сервера **№1**.

Локальный ip по которому открывается сайт "**bbb.ru**" - "192.168.88.253"

Сервер не имеет внешнего ip.

Оба сервера соединены роутером Mikrotik HAP lite (4 порта)

Подключены модули: `a2enmod proxy proxy_http proxy_wstunnel`

Конфигурация на сайте **aaa.ru** `/home/admin/conf/web/aaa.ru.apache2.ssl.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost 111.111.111.111:8443>

    ServerName aaa.ru
    ServerAlias www.aaa.ru
    ServerAdmin info@aaa.ru

    # redirect - который должен перенаправить socket запрос на сервер №2
    <Proxy *>
            Require all granted
    </Proxy>
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyVia on

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      ^/socket.io            [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     transport=websocket    [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)               ws://192.168.88.253:8600/$1 [P,L]
    ProxyPass        :8600/         https://192.168.88.253:8600/
    ProxyPassReverse :8600/         https://192.168.88.253:8600/
    # end

    ... далее без изменений стандартные настройки VestaCP
```

Если подключить на одном из сайтов сервера **№2** Socket.IO,
и сделать настройки .apache2.ssl.conf - как показано выше,
то всё успешно работает, но с сервера **№1** подключения нет, ошибка:
`GET https://www.xxx.ru:8600/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N5zkMiN net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Если в терминале сервера **№1** ввести: `curl https://192.168.88.253:8600`,
то Node.js с сервера **№2** - успешно отвечает.

Как я понимаю, ProxyPass настроенный на сервере **№1** не может получить доступ к локальному ip сервера **№2**, хотя через терминал на сервере **№1** с помощью команды "curl" - всё работает, Node.js  с сервера **№2** отвечает.

Как исправить настройки, что бы Socket.IO с сайта **№1**, мог установить соединение с Node.js на одном из сайтов сервера **№2**,
при условии, что серверы соединены через роутер Mikrotik по локальной сети.

То есть нужно создать соединение, без участия внешнего ip.